# Chat early, chat often!

Tags: discussion, chat

With a title shamelessly stolen from the countless "Vote early, vote often" posts around the network.

In the frenzy of the launch of a new private beta, there's a whole lot of activity going on and it's easy to focus on the Q&A. Remember, though - building the community around this site is important too!

Every new Stack Exchange comes with a chatroom. Yours can be found [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34620/ethereum) - it's also linked in the Stack Exchange site switcher.

Chat is a useful  tool to have in private beta for building the community - not only can you kick back for a while, it's also important to communicate with each other about the stuff going on around the site: what do you want to be on-topic, off-topic, closed, not closed, etc?

Chat is a useful tool, so remember to make use of it.

Answer (score 7):

Having been a part of multiple private betas, I vouch for the importance of the message this post is conveying.

For instance, it took almost three weeks of extensive chatting and meta discussions for properly framing and narrowing down the scope of HardwareRecs, which wouldn't have been possible if the community isn't active on chat and meta.